# Failed to parse model JSON of response from Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, machine-learning

I am trying to load a custom model from Firebase (The custom model is a .json file with three bin files).

The following code saves my custom model (Jupyter notebook, Python):

```
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model2, "model2")
```

Structure of the saved model:

[image]

The following code is using the loadLayersModel (ReactJS):

```
const link = {
    model:
             "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxxxx.appspot.com/o/model2%2Fmodel.json?alt=media&token=f4b6be76-b760-496e-8983-7beda892f5a5",
    
};

const model = await loadLayersModel(link.model);
```

This is the following error (Chrome):

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to parse model JSON of response from https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxxxxx.appspot.com/o/model2%2Fmodel.json?alt=media&token=f4b6be76-b760-496e-8983-7beda892f5a5. Please make sure the server is serving valid JSON for this request.
    at HTTPRequest.load (http.ts:168:1)
    at async loadLayersModelFromIOHandler (models.ts:293:1)
    at async predictionModel (App.js:74:1)
```

These are my rules in firebase storage (Firebase storage):

[image]

I already tried to load a tflite model, but it gave me the same predictions over and over again. So I am trying to understand how to load in a json model from firebase.